# Scaling MongoDB on OpenShift vs using MongoLab

Tags: node.js, mongodb, openshift, mlab

Coming from a "traditional" development background, I cringe whenever I see PaaS NoSQL offerings. The idea of hosting your data far from your application simply does not feel right. But PaaS providers like MongoLab are here and are seemingly very successful.. so I think to myself, it must be working.. I should consider it.

I'm building an application using NodeJS and MongoDB and will be hosting it on OpenShift. Ideally, I have both Web Servers and a Mongo cluster setup that I can easily scale them horizontally... all hosted on OpenShift.

Does it make sense to host/scale Mongo on OpenShift? Should I go with a PaaS like MongoLabs?

**UPDATE:** I'm asking about the architectural reasons why one chose to host data away from your app in a PaaS-type offering vs hosting it yourself in a service like OpenShift. The specific services I'm listing here are irrelevant as it could apply to other hosting service, NoSQL database, or PaaS provider.

Comment: Hey so why did I just get down-voted? Well possibly because you just asked "To recommend a tool or off-site resource". And you actually have an account. So you understand what ["off-topic"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask) means. Don't you? Want your reputation points back? Then remove this. I cannot see how to salvage this as an actual question that is valid here.

Comment: @NeilLunn I'm not asking for a "tool" or "off-site resource" recommendation, I'm asking about the architectural reasons why one chose to host data away from your app in a PaaS-type offering vs hosting it yourself in a service like OpenShift. The specific services I'm listing here are irrelevant as it could apply to other hosting service, NoSQL database, or PaaS provider.

If you feel that I need to rephrase my question, you can suggest that instead of posting an unconstructive comment. Enjoy your day.

Comment: "put on hold as primarily opinion-based"... Opinion-based? Seems like a number of folks are very trigger happy with their "rep". I got the answer I needed below. Thanks.

Comment: I dont see why this should be closed, I was lookig for this exact kind of question and got value from the answer.

Comment: Good question, thanks for having asked this question Ellery Familia. +1 to this question.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

MongoLab is actually a DBaaS (DataBase as a Service) not a PaaS, just for clarification.

The reasons for hosting a database etc offsite is similar to hosting files offsite with say Amazon S3.  You are looking for a service that specializes in what you are using it for.  MongoLab specializes in MongoDB, sharding, replication, large data sets etc.  They would be a great provider if you need those services.  If not, then the MongoDB instance on OpenShift should be fine, you can even use a scaled application to get into it's own gear, but we do not support sharding or replication for MongoDB at this time.